# Embed a website in a website

Tags: browser, embed, html

I have created a website and will be running it in Chrome, fullscreen, on a touchscreen display. Within this website I would like to have an embedded website so that a the user can lookup more information on that product's website without leaving my website. Is there a way to embed a website within a website using HTML, CSS, or JavaScript?

I don't want to use a third party app such Bitty.

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML `<iframe></iframe>` here is a resource on them: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Just keep in mind some sites use `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` which means that website will not work in a `iframe` unless it is hosted on the same domain.

More on `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious response is iframe. Have you considered that?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

`<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width=pixels height=pixels></iframe>`